# How can I change the default name that kate and gedit give to new documents?

Tags: gedit, kate

When you create a new file in `kate` or `gedit` they name them like "Untitled1" or "Unsaved Document 1". How can you change this to some other string$n pattern of your choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just checked the source codes of both the softwares and unfortunately we can't change those names, as those are hardcoded :(

For Kate : http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~neon/kate/kate/view/head:/part/document/katedocument.cpp#L3652

For gedit : https://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit/tree/gedit/gedit-document.c#n1223

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting.  So would changing that and re-compiling be a option?

Comment: Yup. Probably, making them to read from a config file would look great....

Comment: Both these strings are being looked up through a i18n/localisation utility. I'm not sure if either handles these strings at runtime, or if they're hard-coded at compile time - but if you could provide your own localisation strings, that *might* work without a full recompile.